# Resource files not available when running tests from Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, junit, classpath

When I run my JUnit (4.12) test in a `java` Gradle module from within Android Studio, it appears that neither the `main/resrouces`, nor the `test/resources` are available on the classpath.

I tested this by creating `main/resources/test_dir/foo.txt` and `test/resources/test_dir/bar.txt`. In my test method I check whether either one can be read:

```
InputStream fooStream =
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test_dir/foo.txt");
InputStream barStream =
    Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test_dir/bar.txt");
if (fooStream == null && barStream == null) {
    throw new Error("resources unavailable");
}
```

My Gradle module (a dependency to my android app module) that this test code is contained in is named `data`. When I execute tests from the command line (`./gradlew :data:test --rerun-tasks`), the build is successful. When I launch the same tests from Android Studio, the test fails with the above `Error` being thrown.

**How can correctly launch my tests from Android Studio?**

Below, You'l find my test run configuration.
I also found [this Android Studio bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37003772). Could that be the cause?

[image: my test run configuration]

Comment: same issue here. any solution?